# how to get/set textboxvalue in gridview using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a text box inside a GridView as ItemTemplate field. I have a requirement to get the value of the text box usingJquery. How can I do that? How can I get the textbox value under a GridView in Jquery.as well as how can i set new value in this text box.

Comment: you mentioned GridView. Is this an ASP.NET question?

Comment: Are you asking how to find a particular textbox in a GridView and maniuplate it's value or how to manipulate a textbox's value in general? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about GridView specifically, but the jQuery method you can use to get and set the value of a textbox is [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)